# get the number of updated row

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to make a plpgsql function that does a update and then return the number of updated rows.

I found this:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS updated_row_count = ROW_COUNT;
```

It works just fine. However I also found the following in the document of PostgreSQL 9.2 for UPDATE.

```
Outputs
On successful completion, an UPDATE command returns a command tag of the form
UPDATE count
```

This is the link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html

Just wondering how I can get the `count` in plpgsql function.

Comment: Are you looking for something *other* than what "GET DIAGNOSTICS" returns, or just looking for an alternate syntax to "GET DIAGNOSTICS"?

Comment: The other way to get the count of updated/inserter/deleted rows is to add `RETURNING count(*)` to the query.

Comment: @bma I am wondering how to to use `UPDATE count`.

Comment: Pavel answered that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This note is related to low level API, where you can read a "command tag". This API is not available from PL/pgSQL,  or more precisely, it is available via GET DIAGNOSTICS statement.